# MVC - JS window.location.href inserting code into URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is in a MVC app, and this is happening when trying to reset the password

Here is where it is called. Where MVC.Account.Signin references a MVC.js file that returns a URL for that particular action; in this case "/Account/SignIn/" which you can see in the URL

```
            WEBAPI.AccountAPI.FinishResetPassword(function () {
               window.location.href = MVC.Account.SignIn;
               d.resolve();
```

But it redirects to the URL below..

```
https://localhost:44304/Account/function%20()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20url%20=%20%22/Account/SignIn/%22;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20url;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D
```

Where I want it to redirect to

```
https://localhost:44304/Account/SignIn
```

Comment: try "MVC.Account.SignIn()"

Answer (score 0):

looks like SignIn is a function not a string, so you can't assign it to a url